# Prime avoidance lemma (from Eisenbud)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, induction, proof-explanation

I don't quite understand how this proof from Eisenbud goes. If induction on $n$ is used, one should assume that the result holds for $n=k-1$ ($k>1$) and prove it for $n=k$. But the actual induction hypothesis assumes that the lemma fails for $n=k-1$. If the proof is by contradiction and by induction, shouldn't one assume that the contrapositive is true for $n=k-1$ and assume the converse for $n=k$ and arrive at a contradiction?

If what I said above doesn't make sense, I can restate the question as "please clarify the proof of Lemma 3.3." (I don't understand what's happening in general...)

> **Lemma 3.3.** Suppose $I_1,\dots,I_n,J$ are ideals of a ring $R$, and suppose that $J\subset \cup_j I_j$. If $R$ contains an infinite field or if at most two of the $I_j$ are not prime, then $J$ is contained in one of the $I_j$.
>
> Proof. (I omit the case when $R$ contains an infinite field.)
> Induction on $n$. The case $n=1$ is trivial. By induction, we may suppose that $J$ is not contained in any smaller union of the $I_j$, so we can find elements $x_i\in J,x_i$ not in $\cup_{j\ne i} I_j$. Supposing that $J\subset \cup_j I_j$, we must have $x_i\in I_i$.
> If $n=2$, then $x_1+x_2$ is in neither $I_1$ nor $I_2$, contradicting the supposition. If on the other hand $n>2$, then we may assume that $I_1$ is prime, and $x_1+x_2x_3\dots$ is not in any of the $I_j$, again a contradiction.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are *forbidden* on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). Questions should contain sufficient context so that it is [answerable with the text alone](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1807/290189).

Comment: First, this is done via so-called “strong induction”: he is assuming the result holds for *all* values of $k\lt n$, and trying to establish it for $n$. Second, what he is saying is: suppose the result holds for any ideal contained in a union of strictly fewer than $n$ ideals, and let $J$ be contained in a union of $n$ ideals. If it were actually contained in a union of fewer (if some of those $n$ ideals are superfluous), we would be done, so we may assume that $J$ is contained in the union $I_1\cup I_2\cup\cdots\cup I_n$, but that there is no smaller collection of $I_k$s containing $J$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Sorry, I've updated the post.

Comment: Thanks for edit.  I've converted my downvote into upvote since the lemma and its proof is now searchable with [Approach0](//approach0.xyz).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I still don't understand: if he assumes the result for all $k < n$ and proves it for $n$, why does he assume that $J$ is not contained in any smaller union of the $I_j$?

Comment: @user437309: If $J$ were contained in a smaller union of the $I_j$, then you could immediately apply the induction hypothesis and derive the conclusion you want. So in that case, there is nothing further to do, and we just need to consider the case in which that does *not* happen.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin That makes things more clear! But at the step when he assumes $n > 2$, the contradiction must arise from the induction hypothesis. But the induction hypothesis only tells us about $k < n$. How is that contradiction obtained then? Also, I don't understand where he uses that 'at most two of the $I_j$ are not prime'. I can only see that he used that at least one $I_j$ is prime (he used that after assuming $n> 2$).

Comment: @user437309: No, the contradiction does not arise form the induction hypothesis. The contradiction arises because the element $x_1+x_2x_3\cdots$ must be in $J$, but cannot be in any of the $I_j$ and therefore cannot be in the union of the $I_j$; but $J$ is supposed to be contained in the union, so every element of $J$ must be in at least one of the $I_j$. And while I don’t have the book in front of me, I believe there is a comment about how he’s only using that at least one of the $I_j$ is not prime in the inductive step.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks, I see now. But I don't see any comment about what you said (you can still find a screenshot of the proof if you tap "edit" in my question). He only assumes $I_1$ is prime as far as I can see...

Comment: @user437309:As I said, I’m going from memory; I have the vague impression there was a comment sometime after the proof is complete, but I could be wrong. I won’t be able to access my copy of the book until Wednesday in any case.

Comment: If $n>2$ then at least one of the ideals $I_i$ is prime. This is where he uses that 'at most two of the $I_j$ are not prime'.

Comment: @user437309: Right: when $n=3$, he needs to guarantee one of them *is* prime; he can get away with two of them not being prime for $n=2$. Seems like the argument would work with “$n=2$, or $n\gt 2$ and at least one of the ideals is prime”, but then the inductive part would likely break down if the ideal you are omitting is the prime one. By saying “at most two of them are not prime” you also guarantee that any subcollection also has the property, allowing the reduction.

Comment: @user26857: Sorry; the tag should go to the other “user”... Fixed.